# check whether a String contains 3 digits or more

Tags: java, regex

I am looking for a regex to check whether a `String` contains 3 digits or more. Thanks

Comment: Do you really need a regex for this? A simple loop is OK.

Comment: That is not enougn - the string may contain other characters than digits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(?:\D*\d){3}
```

matches if the string contains at least three digits.